# Determining whether a linear operator is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and let $T:\mathcal{L}^{2}([0,t];\mathbb{R}^{m})\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (for some fixed $t>0$) be defined by
\begin{equation*}
  Tx=\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{e}^{A(t-\tau)}Bx(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau.
\end{equation*}
Here, $\mathrm{e}^{A}$ refers to the matrix exponential. Why is it that $T$ is a bounded linear operator? Linearity seems clear to me, but how do I estimate the integral to show the boundedness of $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the series representation of $e^{At}$, one immediately gets (by triangle inequality)
$$
\|e^{A(t-\tau)}\| \le e^{\|A\|(t-\tau)}  \le e^{\|A\|t},
$$
which is independent of the integration variable $\tau$.